# How to hide a label in Rails form(Haml)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, haml

I have a bit of form:

```
  = f.label :option_1, "title"
  = f.check_box :option_1
```

And this is render:

[image: img]
[image: img]
How can I remove "**Option 1**" from label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`= f.check_box :option_1, label: "title"` works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call the label helper method at all!

Rather than

```
= f.label :option_1, "title"
= f.check_box :option_1
```

Use just

```
= f.check_box :option_1
```

Comment: Guessing from the code, I think he rather want to display `'title`'

Comment: I agree that it should, but apparently it does not.

Comment: "Option 1" still visible. I need to remove it or replaced by "title".

Comment: Now I have two visible labels: "title" and "Option 1" and I don't understand why. I don't need "Option 1" :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want "title" and the check box underneath it?  This should work:

```
  = f.label "title"
  = f.check_box :option_1
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, "Option 1" still visible

Answer (score 0):

`= f.label :option_1, "title"
= f.check_box :option_1, label: false`